# Ruby EXIFR can not find file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exif

I am trying to use the EXIF reader and I continue to get the error "Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory"

I have checked and the file most certainly exists in the location I am directing it to:

```
<%= EXIFR::JPEG.new('/system/datas/5/original/IMG_0011.JPG').date_time %>
```

(This is where paperclip puts the files upon uploading)

Any ideas on why I continue to receive this error. I think the problem may not be finding the file but that error is masking the real issue.

I need to retrieve the EXIF data from picture files. Any other ideas are welcome. I am using paperclip to upload files.

Thanks!

Comment: This might sound stupid, but are you sure this particular image has EXIF data?

Comment: I know you said you checked that the file exists, but have you asked Ruby to do so? `p File.exists?('/system/datas/5/original/IMG_0011.JPG')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path you provided to EXIFR is a URL, not a path on the system. Try it:

```
$ ls /system/datas/5/original/IMG_0011.JPG
```

The file is stored in the `public` directory of your rails app, so do something like:

```
EXIFR::JPEG.new(Rails.root.join('public', '/system/datas/5/original/IMG_0011.JPG')).date_time
```

But paperclip also provides a method to access the path, and that is through the `path` method:

```
@model.data.path
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you

```
<%= EXIFR::JPEG.new(Rails.root.join('public/system/datas/5/original/IMG_0011.JPG')).date_time %>
```

Comment: this gave me the following error: NameError: undefined local variable or method `readchar' for #<Pathname:0x007f88581d5dc0>